# jmeter perfmon distributed collecting data

Tags: jmeter, perfmon

I use jmeter perfmon plugin to collect usage of resource. When I run distributed test, each client collect data from server or just master client collect data from? First possibility is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you run test in distributed the master node sends the whole [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) to the slaves and they're independently execute the whole Test Plan.

If you have a [Perfmon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) listener in the Test Plan - it will be executed by **all the slaves**

If you want only one machine to collect metrics (which makes a perfect sense) the options are in:

1. The easiest: create a separate Test Plan which will be doing only performance metrics collection and run it i.e. on master machine in a separate session
2. A little bit harder: create a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) in your main Test Plan and put [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) there. In the If Controller use i.e. [__machineIP() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) like:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${__machineIP()}" =="IP address of the individual slave here",)}
   ```

   once done you can put i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) and attach PerfMon Metrics collector listener to it. This way the Sampler and the Listener will be executed only on the machine which matches the If Controller's condition.